# AFNetworking updating URL in request

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

Is there any easy way to update a request's URL after it was initiated in AFNetworking?
Let's say my app is downloading a 2GB in chunks, we'll have 200 chunks 10MB each. For each I'm creating a AFHTTPRequestOperation and add it to the queue.

Problem is, that the server from which I'm downloading has a timeout on all URLs, which means I'll get 403 after that time and I have to generate a new one. I need to do it before the time runs out.

```
for (DownloadFile *downloadFile in [download filesInTheDownload])
{
    for (DownloadChunk *downloadChunk in [downloadFile chunksInTheFile])
    {
        NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[downloadFile filePath]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
        NSLog(@"Normal range: %lli-%lli", [downloadChunk startingByte], [downloadChunk endingByte]);
        NSString *range = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bytes=%lli-%lli", newStartingByte, [downloadChunk endingByte]];
        [request setValue:range forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:chunkPath append:YES];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chunk complete: %@.%i", [downloadFile fileName], [downloadChunk chunkId]]);
            if (download.downloadedBytes == download.size)
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"downloadFinished" object:download];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];

        [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
            download.downloadedBytes += bytesRead;
        }];

        [queue addOperation:operation];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to modify a scheduled operation. Generally it's a good thing, meaning that you can schedule the operation and be absolutely sure that it's going to be executed based on original conditions.

I see two options in your case. First, you can schedule operations one by one, and verify if the link is valid, updating it if required.

Second, you can react to `403 Forbidden` by updating the link and re-scheduling same operation.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about both cases but thought I could do it also by subclassing the AFHTTPNetworking or something ;)

Comment: Sure, but it brings maintenance complexity ;)